# DateFormat.format returns 01:00:00 with HH:mm:ss format

Tags: java, android, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I am using `android.text.format.DateFormat` to convert a long to hours, minutes and seconds. Here is the code I am testing with:

```
DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", 1000)
```

This returns:

```
01:00:01
```

Why is this? According to the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) reference it should return `00:00:01` but it doesn't. I have tried all combinations and still no difference. I might have to revert to using the `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.to...` methods if DateFormat won't work.

Comment: Note that a date is not a duration or an interval if that's where you're really going with this.

Comment: You are implicitly using UK time for the date 1/1/1970 (epoch) when the timezone was GMT+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateFormat` observes your local time zone. If I understand your question, then you need something like,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String str = df.format(1000);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (as expected)

```
00:00:01
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a slightly different method to yours using a Calendar instance, setting the time zone to UTC, setting the time and using DateFormat as before with the Calendar instance.